# IndexedDb get all occurrences in index

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, indexeddb

In IndexedDb I have an index like this:

```
store.createIndex('distinctEqual', 'distinctEqualString', {unique: false});
```

When I do:

```
var tx = db.transaction(dbSettings.objectStore, "readwrite");
var store = tx.objectStore(dbSettings.objectStore);
var index = store.index('distinctEqual');
var reqIndex = index.get("pippo");
```

Is it possible to get all occurrences of "pippo" without using cursor in that IndexedDb index?

EDIT

If i do:

```
var cursorIndex =       
index.openKeyCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(currItem.distinctEqualString));
cursorIndex.onsuccess = function(evt) {
    //Can I know how many elements are there in cursorIndex?
};
```

As in a comment, can I know how many elements are there in cursorIndex?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a cursor. This is the reason for using a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

The get will only return the first item that meets the keyrange. If you want to retrieve all, you can use the cursor like you mentioned. If you want to know the number of items you can use the [count](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBIndex-count-IDBRequest-any-key) method.

Comment: It isn't possible to use the count method on cursor.

Comment: you can count the number of items by keeping an index while looping over the cursor, but if you only need to know the number of items it's better to use the count method